# Returning a promise from JQuery "on ready" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

According to the [JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), the "recommended" syntax for executing code when the DOM objects become safe to manipulate (a.k.a. "on ready") is this syntax:

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

The JQuery documentation makes no mention of what JQuery does with the return value, if any, provided by the function. Which brings me to my question: **I want to `await` a promise in my function. Is there any reason why I can't decorate the function with the required `async` keyword, like this:**

```
$(async function() {
  await someFuncThatReturnsAPromise();
});
```

According to the excellent [JavaScript.info tutorial on the subject](https://javascript.info/async-await), the `await` keyword causes the function to return a resolved `promise` object. If JQuery doesn't care about the function result, then the fact that the function returns a `promise` object should (hopefully) have no effect on the underlying "call the page ready handlers" JQuery behavior.

Comment: Yes, the return value is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really do anything with the value returned, even if it's a Promise - and, for that reason, is a problem, because if the Promise rejects, you'll get an unhandled rejection:

```js
$(async function() {
  await Promise.reject();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Specifically, what happens with the callback is - it's added as a `.then` handler to the internal `readyList`, and although there's a `.catch` chained onto it, it'll just re-throw the value returned.)

```
var readyList = jQuery.Deferred();

jQuery.fn.ready = function (fn) {

    readyList
        .then(fn)

        // Wrap jQuery.readyException in a function so that the lookup
        // happens at the time of error handling instead of callback
        // registration.
        .catch(function (error) {
            jQuery.readyException(error);
        });

    return this;
};
```

If the async function never rejects, then

```
$(async function() {
  await someFuncThatReturnsAPromise();
});
```

is just fine.

Comment: You said "[It's] a problem, because if the Promise rejects, you'll get an unhandled rejection". Is this any worse (or semantically different) than if my (non-async) code gets an unhandled exception? The unhandled rejection or exception may be a logic error in my code, but do those conditions "break" the JQuery call or cause any other unexpected side-effects in this scenario?

Comment: Halfway decently designed non-async code should never throw (unless you do so deliberately with something like `throw new Error`). In contrast, async code generally can be expected to throw at least in rare cases, like when there's a network problem, or if the server doesn't respond with the expected format, etc. That's why it's recommended to [avoid dangling promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md), but not to add `try/catch` around all synchronous code.

Comment: Whether your call of jQuery results in a rejection or not doesn't really make any difference to jQuery - it's just that having code that could result in a rejection in the first place is ugly and deserves to be refactored.